# ClassNotFoundException with RMI

Tags: java, rmi, classnotfoundexception

i wrote a program in netbeans with RMI that client has error

error :

> java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested
>   exception is:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmiserver.Message
>   (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)  at
>   sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)

but sever does not any error!

interfaace code:

```
 package rmiclient;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface Message extends Remote {
    void sayHello(String name) throws RemoteException;
}
```

interface implementation is:

```
 package rmiserver;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class MessageImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Message {

    public MessageImpl() throws RemoteException {       
    }

    @Override
    public void sayHello(String name) throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("hello "+name);
    }

}
```

server code is:

```
package rmiserver;  
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Main {

    private void startServer(){
        try {
            // create on port 1099
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);

            // create a new service named myMessage
            registry.rebind("myMessage", new MessageImpl());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }     
        System.out.println("system is ready");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.startServer();
    }
}
```

client code is:

```
package rmiclient;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Main {

    private void doTest(){

        try {

            // fire to localhost port 1099
            Registry myRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 1099);


            // search for myMessage service
            Message impl = (Message) myRegistry.lookup("myMessage");

            // call server's method        
            impl.sayHello("edwin");

            System.out.println("Message Sent");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.doTest();
    }
}
```

thanks :).

Comment: And the code doesn't compile.

Comment: my code compiled! BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds) . but will not run

Comment: *This* code doesn't. You have `Message` in package `rmiclient` and the server that implements it in package `rmiserver`, and there are no `import rmiclient.*` statements;

Answer (score 1):

In your stacktrace:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmiserver.Message

but as per data you have provided,  your `Message` interface is declated with package `package rmiclient;` and You haven't created any `rmiserver.Message` class.

Correct the package name.

Comment: thans! but in my orginal code for server and client and interface and implementation used " package rmiserver; "

Comment: Well you still have `rmiclient.Message`, and the error message still says `rmiserver.Message`, so this answer remains correct. You also have your client in the `rmiserver` package, which doesn't make sense if you have an `rmiclient` package. And the code doesn't compile. *Ergo* it is *definitely* not the real code.

Comment: i have 2  copy from message methods. one for client and one for server ! so i need import "rmiclient" in client and import "rmiserver" for server

Comment: i have two package. rmiclient and rmiserver. that in rmiclient are "message" and "main" . in rmiserver are "message" and "main" and "messageimpl"

Answer (score 0):

> I have two package. rmiclient and rmiserver. that in rmiclient are "message" and "main" . in rmiserver are "message" and "main" and "messageimpl"

That's your problem. This doesn't satisfy the contract. You can't just copy `Message` to another package and expect to have it be treated the same as the original. The remote stub implements the same remote interfaces that the remote object does. Not another interface with the same name in another package.

You have to deploy `rmiserver.Message` to the client. Just like the error message says, really.

Comment: that's mean i must have two diffrent interface for server and clients?

Comment: I cannot understand why or how you can possibly be asking that question. That's what you're already doing. The whole point of my answer is *exactly the opposite.* You must *share* the *same* interface between server and client. What you're attempting is meaningless. I thought I had already made that clear.

Comment: You should consider upvoting and/or accepting any answers you find useful here.